# Unable to set privacy for newly created Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create Album that is visible to everyone:

```
FB.api("/me/albums", "post", {
    name: "album name", privacy: '{"value":"EVERYONE"}'
}, function(response) {
    //...
});
```

but it gets created with `friends` privacy.

[Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) say that `privacy` field is:

> A JSON-encoded object that defines the privacy setting for the album, for example: {"value":"SELF"}
>
> value: The privacy value for the object, specify one of EVERYONE, CUSTOM, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, SELF.

I tried `'{"value":"EVERYONE"}'`, `{"value":"EVERYONE"}`, `{value:"EVERYONE"}` - no effect. Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: +1, tried it and it's not working...how about filing a [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/)?

Comment: @ifaour Would you like to create a report and post a link to it in the answer? I would accept it. I just can't login to their bug tracker (confirmation email is never sent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just filed it as a [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19917) in the Facebook Bug Tracker. Please vote.

---

**UPDATE:** This is because of the new "*per-app post privacy control*". Please check @AlexandreCouturon answer.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because the new per-app post privacy control is set to Friends so this App can only set privacy as wide as friends.

Please read the following blog post for more info:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/543/

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to set this new "App privacy" field programmatically? It would make sense if user could select this setting during permission request dialog at least. Is there a way of detecting that this field is set, so before creating an album I can warn users that they would need to manually adjust settings first.