# How to post a wall message and make it visible for EVERYONE?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-wall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to set privacy for newly created Album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125614/unable-to-set-privacy-for-newly-created-album)

I am trying to post a message to a fiend`s wall via JS API. The message is getting posted, but it`s privacy is always "Friends of Friends". How can i make it visible to everyone?

I have tried direct post:

```
FB.api("me/feed", "POST", message, callback);
```

...and ui dialog posting:

```
FB.ui({method: "stream.publish", ...}, callback);
```

Result is always the same -- my message is visible only to friends of friends. I have also tried to set `privacy` field for the message data, without any success.

Default App Activity Privacy == EVERYONE in my application settings.

Comment: no, my per-app privacy is Public

Comment: What about your friend's privacy?

Comment: I don't know what privacy settings my friends use, but i can see a lot of wall posts from some other apps (like 21 question etc) and many of them are marked as "Public". Thats why i am wondering why posts from my app are not public.

Answer (score 0):

try setting both privacy = EVERYONE and friends = EVERYONE

Comment: i get an error: `Error Message: privacy parameters may only be specified if value is 'CUSTOM'`.

Comment: Then `privacy = EVERYONE` should do the job.   I remember there being a lot of bugs.  Might want to try posting this on Facebook support.  Or maybe someone will be able to offer more support.